# Retrive data from database and display in table using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table named ITEM and Price. These are the fields and data of both table

```
Table : ITEM    
item_id | item_name
  1     | ABC
  2     | XYZ,JKL,QWE

Table : Price    
  id    | item_price | item_id
  1     | 50         |  1
  2     | 60         |  2
  3     | 100        |  1
```

Where item_id is reference of ITEM table. I need to create table in php to display all the data from ITEM table. item_name have multiple value seperated with coma. So we need to explode them and use as a drop-down(select) in table.My expected outputt will look like given below.

```
item_id | item_name | item_price
```

Note : item_name must have select option (dropdown)

Comment: is this an assignment for us? show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please remember, SO can help you if have tried your best and stuck somewhere. Its not a free-coding service.

Comment: I need to display data from item and price table using php. Table should contain following column. item_id,item_name and item_price. item_name must have select option (dropdown)

Answer (score 2):

use below query to get records from database

`select a.item,b.item_price from table1 a,table2 b where a.item_id=b.id;`

and then on your  front end(php), try the below

```
$results=mysqli_query($db,"select a.item,b.item_price from table1 a,table2 b where a.item_id=b.id");


if(mysqi_num_rows($result) > 1 )
{

  echo "<table><tr><th>item_id </th><th>item_name</th><th>item_price</th></tr></table>";
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['item_id']."</td>";

    $arry=explode(',',$row['item_name']);
     echo "<td><select>";
     foreach($arry as $value)
      {
        echo "<option>".$value."</option>";
       }
      echo "</select></td>";
     $array=array();
   echo "<td>".$row['item_price']."</td></tr>";

 }
     echo "</table>";
  }
```

Comment: thanks. Query statement is fine but i need php code to display in table format.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file function.php and add following code

```
function result_to_array($result)
{
    $array =array();
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $array[$count]= $row;
        $count++;
    }
    return $array;
}

function GetData(){

    $sql="SELECT * from ITEM,Price where ITEM.item_id=Price.item_id";

    $query=mysql_query($sql);

    $result=result_to_array($query);

    return $result;

}
```

Create a file data.php and include following

```
<?php
include "functions.php";
$data=GetData(); 
?>
<table>
<tr><td>item_id</td><td>item_name</td><td>item_price</td></tr>
<?php foreach($data as $d): ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $d['item_id']; ?></td><td><?php echo $d['item_name']; ?></td><td><?php echo $d['item_price']; ?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

Comment: Superb working. Can you please throw some light on select(drop-down) in item_name field? Because these field shows value with comma separated. I need drop-down instead of comma separated value. thanks

Comment: What your mean by field shows value with comma separated ???
For drop down you can do something like this
<td><select><option value="<?php echo $d['item_name']; ?>"><?php echo $d['item_name']; ?></option></select></td>